# how to fix ckeditor with codeigniter

Tags: php, ckeditor

i am looking to add the ck editor in my website where i want to insert data from back end.i think ck editor is best for this.i searched lots of about this but failed to achieve. **please let me know how to do this in codeigniter.**

**i am getting really confused about using it.some says it will achieve through `<textfield>` 
and some people are works with helper and controller.please guide me to achieve this.step by step answer would be appreciated.**

i tried this code on my view:

```
<?php



include_once  (BASEPATH.'ckeditor/ckeditor.php');

$ckeditor = new CKEditor();
$ckeditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserFlashUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash';
$ckeditor->editor('CKEditor1');

?>
```

and include the js :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

but this url for load the js is failed.please help.

Comment: @DaveP please look at my updated question.

Comment: If you look at the html source on the `<script...` tag, is the generated url correct - in other words is `base_url()` set correctly in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: @DaveP i checked it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the ck editor in codeignitor you just have to follow the below steps:-
1.put the ck editor folder in assets(or in which you want).and give the proper path to js file.
2.now in your view section just include the js file like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

3.now on same file put this code:-

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>
```

4.now you can see the editor on your browser.

Comment: should i create the folder assets?

Comment: no dev its not necessary you can put the ckeditor file wherever you want.but have to give proper path.